# Will be something deleted if I upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04?

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 13.04

I want to upgrade to 13.04 but I dont know if something will be deleted ...

Comment: Please be more specific on the "something". Are you referring to regular user files, packages installed, configuration files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing except for system files should be deleted or modified. Some programs might not be updated (due to the package manager disabling 3rd party repositories), but you shouldn't have any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems upgrading via Terminal form 12.10 to 13.04. I had all the data, but unity was messed up and some other stuff. I would recommend to use a livecd and save all the important data on a usb disk or on a separate partition and make a fresh install.

Good Luck,
phil

Answer (score 0):

For one thing everything in the /var directory is wiped. I lost all my websites I was working on and now have to rebuild from scratch